# How to SHA1 encryption in a Logic App WITH a SecretKey

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, sha1

I need my Azure Logic App to encrypt a value using HMAC SHA1 INCLUDING a Secret Key.  This is necessary as I need to pass the resulting value back to Data Factory to send to an API.  I can successfully run this inside Postman, using JavaScript but now I am forced to run this inside a Logic App.

This is the logic I am TRYING to achieve:

`AccessKey + : + (  base64(    SHA1(date: requestId : uri : application key, secretkey)))`

Can anyone help please?

My Infrastructure Team have rejected standing up the infrastructure to write an Azure Function.

I have tried to construct this manually in SQL in a loop using this methodology:

`base64ToString(concat('SHA1-', base64ToString(concat('HMAC-', base64ToString('this is the secret key'), ':','Thu, 20 Apr 2023 02:37:33 UTC:RandomHexcodeGoesHere:/api/training/campaign/get-everything:AccesskeyGoesHere'))`

and this script 3 times over, adding the concat value to the output of the previous run and then re-running:

```
`DECLARE @input varchar(100)
DECLARE @encoded varchar(100)

SET @input = 'secret key:value that needs to be converted'
SET @encoded = (SELECT CAST(N'' AS    XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
            FROM (SELECT CAST(@input AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS bin) AS bin_sql_server_temp)

SELECT @encoded`
```

but that hasn't worked out properly either.  Ideally I would run everything I need inside SQL, so taking out the overhead of the logic app, or failing that I would be able to use a prebuilt module inside the Logic Apps to do this automagically, but the Hashify one doesnt appear to use the Secret Key.

Does anyone have a suggestion please? Or a way around this.  I am stumped.